# How do I pass the state of a custom designed checkbox to a JSP page?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a form with a custom designed checkbox (using CSS) that I would like to pass the state of to a JSP page for persisting to a database.

Here's the code for my checkbox:

```
<div class="checkbox" title="Automatically activate microphone"> <span class="box"    role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" tabindex="17" aria-labelledby="setting1"></span>
    <label class="checkmark"></label>
    <label class="text" id="setting1">Automatically activate microphone.</label>
</div>
```

I can get the state of the checkbox using JavaScript, but I'm not sure how to then pass that value to my JSP page for processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hidden input type which will have same value as checkbox value

```
<div class="checkbox" title="Automatically activate microphone"> <span class="box"    role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" tabindex="17" aria-labelledby="setting1"></span>
    <label class="checkmark"></label>
    <label class="text" id="setting1">Automatically activate microphone.</label>
    <input type = "hidden" value = "checkBoxValue" name = "someName">
</div>
```

You can change the value of hidden type based on checkbox state using javascript

Now after submitting form, you can access the checkbox value in your JSP using EL `requestScope['someName']` or `request.getParameter("someName")`

Comment: Thanks, that's such a simple solution that I totally overlooked!